# How to Download a Folder with subfolder with all file inside the folder from SharePoint Online using c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I try to dowload all folder structure from sharepoint online, I try some code here Thanks for your help:

```
public void DownloadFilesAndFolders(ClientContext _ctx, Folder folder, string localFolder)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(folder);
            Console.WriteLine(localFolder);


            _ctx.Load(folder, k => k.Files, k => k.Folders);
            _ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var folders in folder.Folders)
            {
                string folderPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", localFolder, folder.Name);

                Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

                DownloadFilesAndFolders(_ctx, folder, folderPath);
            }

           
              
            

        }
      
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Does this code work, not work, throw an error or ??

Comment: My code is not working, actually I can not get the subfolder of my folder libray.

Comment: There's a lot missing to the question. Did you forget to include the error message? What guide are you following? What are the permissions on the subfolder?